SceneKit USDZ file showing the wrong model

I purchased a 3D model file, and its FBX format. I opened it in blender, and the model looks like this:



Then I open it in Apple's Reality Converter, and it looks like this:



Then I convert it into USDZ file. And import it into my Xcode project, which looks like this:



Then I wrote some code, put it on screen. Guess what - the model is changed to something completely different:


I have attached a sample project here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NMhiYPR5u4ghw0voxbyOjiXOutj8aoEG/view?usp=sharing
I don't know what's going on with the model file. The company selling it seems legit. Maybe they exported the wrong FBX file? But how come it shows the correct model in blender and reality converter?

It seems, the method you use to import models does kind of inaccurate interpretation...
I got your model (USDZ and/or converted SCN) working by using a slight different import mechanism)
Add this extension somewhere:
extension SCNNode {
    convenience init(named name: String) {
        self.init()
        guard let scene = SCNScene(named: name) else {return}
        for childNode in scene.rootNode.childNodes {addChildNode(childNode)}
    }
}

Then use it like so:
override init() {
    super.init()
    
    let camera = SCNCamera()
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = camera
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 50)
    rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
    
    // *** Changed Section ***
    let geo32 = SCNNode(named: "Audio_07.usdz") // or Audio_07.scn, if you converted it to SCN
    geo32.scale = SCNVector3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5) // OPTIONAL
    geo32.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(CGFloat.pi/2, 0.0, 0.0) // OPTIONAL
    rootNode.addChildNode(geo32)
    
}

This are the results:
For the USDZ (I have no editor installed, you might need to adjust the materials)

For the converted SCN (I added some colors to the Materials)

Hopefully this will help you.

it looks like there are multiple geometries under the root node? Is it possible to combine the geometries into 1 single geometry? I have to use single geometry because it's easier to attach a physics body with that geometry

if you want to use a single geometry, you can use the flattenedClone() method: let geo32 = SCNNode(named: "Audio_07.usdz").flattenedClone(); geo32.scale = SCNVector3(25, 25, 25); rootNode.addChildNode(geo32) - Do not set the Euler-Angle in this case.

with this approach the texture doesn't work anymore.

can you share the code for setting up the texture?

I can't use the SCNScene(named:) because my assets would have to be in main bundle, but in real game, the assets are in framework bundle

It seems after flattening it, the submeshes' coordinate is wrong

i guess it's a separate issue. i will create a new question. Will accept your answer then.

There you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79302373/scenekit-flattenedclone-changes-the-node-unexpectively
