SceneKit flattenedClone changes the node unexpectively
I have a 3D model that contains 3 geometries, as highlighted below

This is my code that create such SCNNode from a USDZ file:
  private func readGeo(fn: String) -> SCNNode {
    let bundle = Bundle.main
    let url = bundle.url(forResource: fn, withExtension: nil)!
    let asset = MDLAsset(url: url)
    asset.loadTextures()
    let object = asset.object(at: 0)
    let node = SCNNode(mdlObject: object)
    return node
  }

Then I need to flatten the node, since I want to make it just a single geometry, so that it's easier to attach a physics body. So I changed the return to:
return node.flattenedClone()

The position of geometries seems to be incorrect, as you can see below: (see the cover is sticking out)

You can download the sample project here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ewudz3A2NKeW-72bXRPJJtphyRMae-1e/view?usp=sharing
Edit:
I realize that the position of the sub nodes are changed after flatten. They are originally at non-zero coordinate, but after flatten, they are positioned as if they are at zero coordinate. I don't know why

Question: Will you later apply different Materials, or will you use one single Material?

The problem seems to be related, how the model is organised in its own node tree and subnode structure. The "empty" subnodes give position, scale, and even some rotation to the final models. If I remove them in blender, the model looks exactly the same way, as your "creepy" sample image. The Apple internal process of how a flattened clone is merged together remains Apple's secret. I consider you to re-arrange your model in a way that places all geometry nodes to top level and get rid of your submode trees. For exporting the model I consider you to use a Collada (DAE) instead of the USDZ.

I adjusted your Model in Blender. Please try it again in your Project. Flattened Cloning should now work as expected. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gWf4KLSbPv2lbsOyDX-AJI83Q-L0GCs8/view?usp=sharing

I can't modify the models - i bought like 600 models and it's unreasonable to modify each one of them

If you have this large amount of models, I only can hope, they are not all in the same style as your walkman model. You might probably need to develop a way/function, that is able to detect the models (in the tree) which contain geometry... and add them to some intermediate node for final flattened cloning. But still you would have then the problem to correct inaccurate positionings etc... sounds like a hard job... For the moment I have no better solution or answer for you.

do you think it's a bug in SceneKit? maybe i can file a radar?

It could be a bug, but it's very very hard to prove. As far as I know, Apple will kindly ignore this. If 100 devs file the same bug, then probably they gonna react.

I believe this is a bug in SceneKit that the transform is ignored if the node has no geometry. I was able to fix its by passing down the transforms to child nodes with a DFS:

fileprivate extension SCNNode {
  
  // pre-process it before taking the flattenedClone()
  var preProcessed: SCNNode {
    let clone = self.clone()
    Self.dfs_passDownTransform(node: clone)
    return clone
  }
  
  static func dfs_passDownTransform(node: SCNNode) {
    // If it's an empty node with just transform, we want to pass the transform to its immediate children
    if node.geometry == nil && !SCNMatrix4IsIdentity(node.transform) {
      for child in node.childNodes {
        child.transform = SCNMatrix4Mult(child.transform, node.transform)
      }
      node.transform = SCNMatrix4Identity
    }
    
    for child in node.childNodes {
      dfs_passDownTransform(node: child)
    }
  }
}

